# write Debezium Kafka topic data to Hive through HDFS sink connector not work

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I try to capture MySQL data changes with Debezium MySQL connector to Kafka, then write the changes finally to Hive on Hadoop through HDFS Sink connector. The pipeline is like: MySQL -> Kafka -> Hive.

The sink connector is configured like following screenshot.

```yaml
{
  "name": "hdfs-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "customers",
    "hdfs.url": "hdfs://192.168.10.15:8020",
    "flush.size": "3",
    "hive.integration": "true",
    "hive.database":"inventory",
    "hive.metastore.uris":"thrift://192.168.10.14:9083",
    "schema.compatibility":"BACKWARD",
    "transforms": "unwrap,key",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.key.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.key.field": "id"
  }
}
```

This seems working but querying the Hive table and I see the changed data (wrapped in `after` key is displayed in `after` conlumn instead of delimiting the data into original table columns.

Here is the query result scrrenshot.

[image]

As you can see in sink configuration, I already try to use Debezium's `"io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope"` operator to unwrap the event message but obviously it is not working.

What is the minimal settings that can let me write the DB change events from Kafka to Hive? Is it HDFS Sink connector the right choice for this job?

**Update**: 
I test this with the sample "inventory" database from Debezium database. 
I got the test environment from Debezium images so that they should be the lastest ones. Some version info here: debezium 1.0, kafka 2.0, confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs sink connector: 5.4.1.

**update 2**:
I moved on to use following sink config, but still no luck:

```yaml
{
  "name": "hdfs-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "dbserver1.inventory.customers",
    "hdfs.url": "hdfs://172.17.0.8:8020",
    "flush.size": "3",
    "hive.integration": "true",
    "hive.database":"inventory",
    "hive.metastore.uris":"thrift://172.17.0.8:9083",
    "schema.compatibility":"BACKWARD",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's better if you can post the actual config, not a screenshot - then people can copy and paste it to try it out and run locally to help answer your question :)

Comment: What version of Debezium are you running? If you use something like `kafkcat` to inspect the topic that Debezium is writing to, do you see the `before` / `after` structure?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, I can get the good `before/after` structure with every message in Kafka topic. Thanks